# Can someone explain me why .env variables are undefined when I print them?

Tags: javascript, node.js, environment-variables, nodejs-server

I've done a Node JS server with ES6 using import and export, but when I want to access to an enviroment variables to print that, they return me "undefined". This is my code :

```
import express from 'express'
import bodyParser from 'body-parser'
import cors from 'cors'
import 'babel-polyfill'
import userRoutes from './routes/user.routes.js'
import db from './db/database.js'
import dotenv from 'dotenv'

dotenv.config()

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5001
const app = express()
db.connection()

app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '30mb', extended: true }))
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: '30mb', extended: true }))
app.use(cors())

app.use(userRoutes)

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello world')
})
app.listen(PORT, () => {console.log(`Server on port ${process.env.PORT} and secret key ${process.env.JWT_KEY}`)})
```

Comment: Have you set the environment variables?

Comment: Use a better configuration tool:  [wj-config](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wj-config)

Answer (score 0):

Only thing I can think of is your `.env` file not being in root folder.

move your `.env` file to root folder and your environment variables should be loaded to your application.

Answer (score 0):

If your `.env` file is not in the root of your project you can manually set it's path via this code :

```
const path = require('path')

require('dotenv').config({ path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../.env') })
```

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you install dotenv package. and .env file is in root path if it is not in root path then setup path of dotend

Example:

```
dotenv.config({''}) //here you can set your .env file location.
```